# How to send a touch event to iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, uitouch

Im writing an app running in background on a jailbreak iphone. I need to send touch event to iPhone OS to simulate finger touches. Is this possible?

Comment: can any one help me to get out a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460614/simulate-touch-on-ios7-8

Answer (score 2):

See Matt Gallagher's article ["Synthesizing a touch event on the iPhone"](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html).  You may also check out the [Three20 framework](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html), which I believe used synthesized touch events to test UI elements (leading to a rash of recent [application rejections](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/msg/aa896b3046a4b06e) due to the use of private APIs).

Comment: thanks, Brad. In Matt Gallagher's article, synthesized touch event only works to views. I'm still looking for some way to simulate system level touch event.

Comment: @xiaoma imagine you could send system-wide events like that without user interaction - wouldnt that introduce a huge risk of ppl using it to do things that the user does not want (e.g. call a dubious hotline while he is asleep)

Comment: hi, Brad. What i want to do is something like Veency except that it can accept multitouch input. Imagine that i can control iphone using my macbook multitouch trackpad.

Comment: Some of Matt Gallagher's excellent article is no longer functional. I've updated it, and included some other functionality, in a category on UITapGestureRecognizer. Some of the techniques may be helpful.

It's on the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16471965/1532399

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, using GSEvents. Try the KennyTM's private framework and GSEvent.h. It is under the GraphicServices framework.
https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks

Comment: this github repo is deprecated and the links to other repo related are two.