# How to simulate a click in a webpage in iOS with objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I'm looking for an equivalent of Mechanize (Ruby/python and more) for iOS.

I need to simulate a click in a webpage (form submission) and get the response back. I tried to construct a POST-request using ASIHTTPRequest without succes. I was able to create a solution in Ruby (with Mechanize) but I want to be able to do the same in objective-c for iphone development. Any suggestions ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send a touch event to iPhone OS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746452/how-to-send-a-touch-event-to-iphone-os) and [Simulate touch on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4137205/643383)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the duplicated posts, the API to programmatically simulate touches is private, so not appropriate for a shipping app. Follow the links if you want to know how to do it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Caleb, I guess my only way to achieve my goal is getting a succesful response to a POST-request of the actual form (if i wanted to still get the app in the market) or getting the response of my ruby script, only downside of this is that it will always request target site with a static server ip instead of the user client ip of the iphone itself..